# Calucate the coefficient of taylor series

Tags: taylor-expansion

Suppose $f$ is a real valued function with $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(x) = 1/\sqrt{1+x^2}$. I want to calculate the coefficient of the $x^7$ term around $0$.

My approch: Although I know the answer if given $$f^{(7)}(0)/7!,$$ I am unable to calculate that far. I was hoping if there is shorter way to get the answer given the fact that this question was previously asked in an exam.

Comment: If you know the binomial expansion, then you can get this easily.

Comment: @SeanRoberson You want me to expand $(1 + x^2)^{-0.5}$ and check for the coefficient of $x^6$ term i.e. $(^{-.5}C_3) \times 6! / 7!)$.

Comment: @SeanRoberson But how is binomial related to taylor series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not difficult to find the Taylor  series of $(1-t)^{\alpha}$ around $0$:
$$(1+t)^{\alpha}=1+\alpha x+\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)}{2!}x^2+\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)(\alpha-2)}{3!}x^3+\cdots$$

Put $t=x^2$, $\alpha=-1/2$, the Taylor  series of $f'(x)=(1+x^2)^{-\frac12}$ around $0$ is given by
$$f'(x)=1-\frac12x^2+\cdots+\frac{-\frac12(-\frac12-1)(-\frac12-2)}{3!}x^6+\cdots$$
Take the sixth derivative and put $x=0$,
$$f^{(7)}(0)=\left.\frac{d^6}{dx^6}f'(x)\right|_{x=0}=0+\frac{-\frac12(-\frac12-1)(-\frac12-2)}{3!}(6!)+0.$$